# Is hibernate Validation different that JSR bean Validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

Suppose i use

```
@NotEmpty
private Name;
```

Now as it is from `org.hibernate.validator.constraint.NotEmpty`

Now in my controller

How can i use annotation that work with hibernate because hibernate jar has no @Valid in their jar file

also How does hibernate knows which error message to display in `<form:error` fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also add the validation api jar to your classpath.

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/validation/validation-api/

The Hibernate Validator documentation provides some information on how messages are interpolated.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation

Comment: i am confused hibernate says they have all constraint that were in JSP and some more but on hibernate-validator jar file i find only 4 constraints. I can't find NotBlank constraint which is written on their site

Comment: The annotation itself is probably in the validation-api.jar. Hibernate provides the validators that are associated with the annotation.

Comment: so if i use any contraint in bean then do i have t0 import persistence.contraint or hibernate.contraint

Comment: I would start by using those from the validation api. But why don't you give it a try and see what happens.